# jQuery UI resizable bug(?) in Firefox and IE

Tags: jquery, firefox, css-tables, resizable

I'm building an HR module for a company, using sortable tables with dynamic content. After finishing the project, the client requested to make the tables resizable vertically. I applied **jQuery UI resizable()** to the div the main table is wrapped into. It works absolutely fine in *Safari* and *Chrome*, but when resizing the wrapper div in Firefox or IE, the table's height stays the same, and doesn't expand to the div's dimensions.

The simplified markup looks like this:

```
<div id="list">
    <div class="table-container">
        <table>
            (blablabla, this is a sortable table with clickable th's and about 10 columns)
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

The styles are:

```
#list {
    width: 1150px;
    height: 180px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #aeaeae;
}

#list .table-container {
    width: 1145px;
    height: 175px;
}

#list table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}

#list table td {
    height: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I've tried using various **overflow**, **position** and **display** values to each element, but the result wasn't any better. The jQuery part is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#list .table-container").resizable({ alsoResize: "#list", handles: "s" });
});
```

Is there really an issue like this with Firefox/IE, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If possible, it's always helpful to test these things out side of a dev environment, like [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), where you can separate the essential components of your code to perhaps isolate any problem causers. When I'm working on things that are populated dynamically, I just fill it with dummy data and build it independently of the application elsewhere. I also could not reproduce this.

Answer (score 0):

Tested your code in Firefox 9.0.1.
Couldn't find a problem.

The table height did change as the div was re-sized.

I found the table to re-size properly on Firefox, IE and chrome.

I don't think there is anything wrong with FF or IE.
Guess something else in your code is affecting it.